# get the count for different data in single column as set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am having table "Activation" with the columns **account ID** and **email** and **product name**

**product name** column is having data like this below

```
 Platform
 Access
 Onboard
 OnGuard
 Platform
 Access
 Onboard
 OnGuard
```

when user activated we will insert the data as a set like this **( Platform
     ,Access
     ,Onboard
     ,OnGuard)**
and i need to give a warning to the user  if he is inserting more than one set **(Platform,Access,Onboard,OnGuard)**

I can get the count for single product name insertion like (platform or access), but i need to get the count for single set insertion here ..

Could any one please help on this query how to get count for single set insertion and i am using sql server as a DB for these insertions.

Many thanks in advance..

**UPDATE**

**sorry for confusion i need to give a warning to user if  he inserted more than one time any of the product name defined in the set not as a single set ..**

Comment: If you are after a unique entry, just add a unique index on the table, your code will get thrown with an exception you can catch and display a warning

Comment: Your question is not well defined.  What happens if, after adding a set of four, the user attempts to add `Platform` four times?  Does that also throw an error?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that unique products count is `4`, you can check it using aggregation along with `having`.

```
select accountid
from activation
group by accountid
having count(distinct productname) = 4
```

Or you can reverse the logic according to your need(if you want to get the users against whom not all products are defined by changing `=` to `<>`

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/LHBLZ63450)**

Comment: thanks for  the reply.. i need to give a warning to user if he inserted  more than one time any of the product name and we need to check whether he generated as set also..

Comment: Still your question is not clear. As far as i can understand the question, If you need a warning at application level, you can first check if all products are entered via the query above after the insertion. For a single entry before insertion, you can just use a simple `select` query to check whether `x` product exists or not against `y` id.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use this In Trigger.

```
DECLARE @Product_Name NVARCHAR(50)
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM Activation WHERE productname = @Product_Name) BEGIN

    RAISERROR ('Product Name  Already Exists', 16, 1)

END
```